# Kendo grid.saveChanges() error handling

Tags: jquery, post, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid that I am adding a new item to (POST), there is a chance for a 409 error (duplicate item), how can i handle this? I NEED to use grid.saveChanges(), it's a requirement. The code below works, I just need to handle errors with it.

(I replaced the actual values with "values")

```
var dataSource = grid.dataSource;
dataSource.add( {
    Values: data.values
});
grid.saveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dataSource: z.dataSource({
    transport: {
        create: {
            url: "/url/url",
            type: "POST",
            complete: function (e) {
                if (e.status == 409) {
                    // Duplicate Items are not allowed
                }
            }
        }     
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is some code that I use for handling save errors for a grid

```
//This works with post 2014 Kendo Update.
function NewError_Handler(e)
{
    if(e.errors)
    {



        $(".k-grid").each(function () {
            var grid = $(this).data("kendoGrid");
            if (grid !== null && grid.dataSource == e.sender) {
                // We have a winner!
                grid.one("dataBinding", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                });


                var message = "";
                $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                    if ('errors' in value) {
                        $.each(value.errors, function () {
                            message += this + "<br/>";
                        });
                    }
                });

                $('#errorWindow').removeClass('hidden');
                $('#errors').text("");
                $('#errors').append(message);
            }
        });




    }
}
```

this then applies the errors this piece of html (loaded as a partial view for me MVC)

```
<div id="errorWindow" class="panel panel-danger hidden ">
    <div class="panel-heading">Errors Found </div>
    <div class="panel-body panel-danger">
        <div id="errors">

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

this is called via the Error event handler within the datasource setup.

This link should help with you setting it up 
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#events-error

(I generally use the MVC wrappers for my kendo needs)

Hope this helps.